# JList row display

Tags: java, swing, jlist

How can I fix the number of rows being displayed regardless of the number of objects in my JList? For example, how would I go about displaying 5 rows in a JList when the JList contains 4 or fewer items?

Answer (score 5):

You mean JList's `setVisibleRowCount(int count)` method?

This is all you need to do. For example, here's a JList with just 3 items, but 5 rows are showing due to the method above, and due to the JList being displayed within a JScrollPane:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestJLIst {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JList<String> list = new JList<>(new String[] {"A", "B", "C"});
      list.setVisibleRowCount(5);
      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(scrollPane);
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
   }
}
```